# Query always returns 1064 syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I use `'MariaDB 5.5 x64' and Client HeidiSQL`.
server environment is Windows Server2012 Datacenter.
And database `use_progress` a row is following

> int id  //auto-incremental primary key
>   int owner  //owner user's unique id
>   varchar[20] name  //key
>   int value  //value

it stores online game user's states key-value type

for example

```
id  owner name           value
856 656   stage0cleared  0
857 656   have_gold      10214  
858 657   inventory      22
```

and the next query's working test is fine

```
select count(*) from use_progress where owner = 656 and name = "inventory";

INSERT INTO use_progress (use_progress.owner, use_progress.name, use_progress.value) VALUES (656, 'inventory', 7);

UPDATE use_progress SET use_progress.value = 7 WHERE use_progress.`owner` = 656 AND use_progress.`name` = 'inventory';
```

but the next query is error 1064 (syntax error)

```
BEGIN  
    IF ((select count(*) from use_progress where owner = 656 and name = "inventory") = 0 )   THEN  
        INSERT INTO use_progress (use_progress.owner, use_progress.name, use_progress.value) VALUES (656, 'inventory', 7);  
    ELSE  
        UPDATE use_progress SET use_progress.value = 7 WHERE use_progress.`owner` = 656 AND use_progress.`name` = 'inventory';  
    END IF;  
END
```

the error is folling next(always that error):

```
/* SQL error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF ((select count(*) from use_progress where owner = 656 and name = "inventory")' at line 2 */
```

I tried everything I could. Use () or not, insert *dbname.tablename.* prefix to every column name or not. But in every situation, the same error occurs.

I even tried this (line 2 is changed):

```
BEGIN  
    IF (1>2)   THEN  
        INSERT INTO use_progress (use_progress.owner, use_progress.name, use_progress.value) VALUES (656, 'inventory', 7);  
    ELSE  
        UPDATE use_progress SET use_progress.value = 7 WHERE use_progress.`owner` = 656 AND use_progress.`name` = 'inventory';  
    END IF;  
END
```

But same error occurs (message is same)
I don't know why this happen.

Comment: Have you changed the delimiter? You can use BEGIN ... END only in stored routines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use control structures like `IF() THEN ...` in simple queries, only in stored procedures or functions.

In this case you'd use a stored procedure. Try like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc_name(IN p_owner int, IN p_name varchar(50), IN p_value int)
BEGIN  
    IF NOT EXISTS (select 1 from use_progress where owner = p_owner and name = p_name) THEN  
        INSERT INTO use_progress (owner, name, `value`) VALUES (p_owner, p_name, p_value);  
    ELSE  
        UPDATE use_progress SET `value` = p_value WHERE `owner` = p_owner AND `name` = p_name;  
    END IF;  
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

After creating it, you'd call it like this:

```
CALL my_proc_name(656, 'inventory', 7);
```

Comment: it works. i don't know the *procedure* because i'm first time at DB. this 'precedure concept' give me many solutions for my DB Design problem. thank you.